# Using find command in bash in order to find multiple files with different types

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am running test scenarios. Each time I a scenario is executed, there are two report files in a specific directory; one is a text file and another is the an HTML file. I want to make an index file to link to all files. I have wrote a for loop to iterate over scenario files and execute them; I also want to read the final result of my test scenario from HTML file and append it to the index file. At the end of the loop, I append `<a>` tags for links using find command.

```
for line in $(grep '^scenario ' $scenarioList | cut -d' ' -f2)
do
    # Scripts for running tests
    find -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'f="`basename {}`"; echo "<br><span>Text Report: <a href="./$f" target="_blank">$f</a> -- </span>" >> index.htm' \;
    find -name '*.html' -exec sh -c 'f="`basename {}`"; p=`cat $f | grep -Eo "Final Result :.*\." | cut -d"." -f1`; echo "<span>HTML Report: <a href="./$f" target="_blank">$f</a></span> -- <span>$p</span><br>" >> index.htm' \;
    # Other scripts
done
```

It should creates link to text file, link to HTML file and the final result of each scenario in a single line separated by `--`.

If I run this scripts over a single scenario, everything seems right:

[image]

But if I run it over more scenarios, this creates wrong links:

[image]

I know that I can use `-o` option for logical OR, but I don't know how to separate the text file and the HTML file from each other for creating links. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Are you filenames always in this form (`*blog.txt` and `*_style-all.html`). If so, you could do simple text translation.

Comment: No @knittl, the pattern is just like I used in the command. I just know there are two files, one with `.html` extension and the other with `.txt` extension.

Comment: But could you please explain me the `text translation` you have talked about @knittl? Maybe that helps.

Comment: Grep for all `*blog.txt` files, and then when generating the links, replace `blog.txt` with `_style-all.html`

Comment: It's not clear what your `for` loop loops over. What's in `line` and how is it used? It is also not clear what your directory structure looks like. The output looks like you would expect from one `find` to pick up text files followed by another to pick up HTML files, but without more details about how your stuff is organized, we can't suggest alternatives with any useful precision. "Don't do that, then" is pretty much the best we can offer for this problem statement.

Comment: @tripleee, this script is executing in a directory which contains just one text file and one HTML file in each iterate of the for loop. The `line` contains some information about the scenario which is going to be executed and it has been just used for the execution scripts; it can't help us to create index file.

Comment: That's not what your generated output suggests.  It traverses multiple directories and finds the text reports, then the HTML reports.  If the HTML report's name is predictable from the text report's (or vice versa) it's probably not hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `-o` and `-printf` options of `find`

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '<br><span>Text Report: <a href="%p" target="_blank">%f</a> -- </span>' -o  -name '*.html' -printf '<span>HTML Report: <a href="%p" target="_blank">%f</a></span>'
```

I may have messed up your formatting there, but I think you get the idea.

The %p option prints the full file path, relative to the search and %f prints the filename

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was really useful; I can now have related files in a line. But there was something else that you have missed. I want to read the result line from HTML file which is starting with `Final Result :` and add it to the end of the line in index file. What do you propose for that?

Comment: you mean like `grep "Final Result: " filename`?

Comment: No, `Final Result: ` is a part of HTML file's content.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi yes, but you should still be able to grep for it

Comment: Yes, I can grep for it. Could you please give me an answer for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this instead.  This presumes that the text file's name can be predicted from the HTML file's name.  I have also refactored your shell script where it seemed unidiomatic and/or inefficient.

```
grep '^scenario ' "$scenarioList" |
cut -d' ' -f2 |
while read -r line; do
    # Scripts for running tests
    find -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
        f="$(basename {} _style-all.html)";
        echo "<br><span>Text Report: <a href="./${f}blog.txt" target="_blank">${f}blog.txt</a> -- </span>";
        h=$(grep -Eo "Final Result :.*\." {} | cut -d"." -f1);
        echo "<span>HTML Report: <a href="./${f}_style-all.html" target="_blank">${f}_style-all.html</a></span> -- <span>$p</span><br>"'
    # Other scripts
done >index.html
```